# How to deploy jar file to subdomain host folder in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, subdomain

I'm running `tomact7` on centos.

I'm running my website `example.com` on a tomcat server. My `server.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
         prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
         pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  <Context docBase="ROOT" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebsiteHome"/>
</Host>
```

In my project's `pom` file, I'm using `tomcat7` plugin. Whenever I have a new war file, I deploy it to tomcat with this command:

```
$ curl -X PUT -v -u username:password -T WebsiteHome-0.0.1.war 'http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/&update=true'
```

If I want to run my website, I run the following commands:

```
$ service tomcat start
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

---

I'm trying to run a domain `example.com` and a subdomain `academy.example.com`

I modified my `server.xml` file; removed `localhost` Host and add 2 new hosts like this:

```xml
<Host name="example.com"  appBase="webapps"
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
         prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
         pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  <Context docBase="ROOT" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebsiteHome"/>

</Host>
<Host name="academy.example.com"  appBase="webapps2"
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
         prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
         pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  <Context docBase="ROOT" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebsiteTrainingCenter"/>
</Host>
```

After that, I run `service tomcat restart`, and tomcat automatically generates some new files and directories

```
$ tree /usr/share/tomcat
.
├── bin
├── conf
│   ├── Catalina
│   │   ├── academy.example.co
│   │   ├── example.co
│   │   └── localhost
│   └── ... [OTHER-XML-FILES-HERE]
├── lib
├── logs
├── temp
├── webapps
├── docs
│   └── ...
├── examples
│   └── ...
├── host-manager
│   └── ...
├── manager
│   └── ...
├── ROOT
│   └── ...
└── sample
    └── ...
├── webapps2
└── work
    └── Catalina
        ├── academy.example.co
        │   ├── _
        │   ├── examples
        │   ├── host-manager
        │   └── sample
        ├── example.co
        │   ├── _
        │   ├── docs
        │   ├── examples
        │   ├── host-manager
        │   ├── manager
        │   └── sample
        └── localhost
            ├── _
            ├── docs
            ├── examples
            ├── host-manager
            ├── manager
            │   └── ...
            └── sample
```

My question is how can I deploy war files now? How can I use the previous `curl` command to specify what host should I deploy to?

If I used the same curl command after I removed `localhost` Host & add the new hosts, I get 404 error:

```
$ curl -X PUT -v -u username:password -T WebsiteHome-0.0.1.war 'http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/&update=true'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=/&update=true HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 176151710
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 12:38:44 GMT
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

How can I deploy my two new war files(one for domain and the other for subdomain), and specify that each one of them should be deployed on a different host?

Comment: is it really localhost?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the manager context is set when there's no `Context` defined in your application. Seems like the `server.xml` was changed in order to support multiple virtual hosts.

For your `curl` deploy command to work in your newly set Virtual Hosts, you'll need to setup the manager context for each one of them, as the [docs says](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Introduction):

> If you have Tomcat configured to support multiple virtual hosts (websites) you would need to configure a Manager for each.

It's as easy as copying the `manager` folder from the default `webapp.dist` included in the `tomcat7` installation folder and setting up the `Context` in your `server.xml`:

```
<Host name="example.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
         prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
         pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  <Context docBase="ROOT" path="" reloadable="true" />
  <Context docBase="manager" path="/manager" reloadable="true" privileged="true" />
</Host>
```

After that, you'll be able to `curl` your `war` files by specifying the virtual host in the URL instead of `localhost`, something like this:

```
$ curl -X PUT -v -u username:password -T WebsiteHome-0.0.1.war 'http://example.com:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/&update=true'
```